# How do you generate your initial storage for deployment in ligo?

Tags: smart-contracts, ligo

I'm curious about your strategies regarding the following questions:

1. How do you generate your initial storage for deployment ? Where do you store your storage types ? Do you keep your storage definitions in separate files from the code itself?
2. More generally, how do you organize your code? Do you place all the contract components in one file (types, storage, parameters, main, actions, local functions, views)? I tried to efficiently share some types, particularly the storage (I have a generic factory that needs to know the storage types of each created contract). However, I ended up with numerous small files, which made it very difficult to read. I plan to rework this, but I'm curious to hear some opinions and best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Taquito and define initial storage in my deploy script.
You have several exemples of code oragnization and deployment script in template contracts https://packages.ligolang.org/contracts

Answer (score 0):

It's common to have separate files. In particular, I've seen separate files for storage - in `storage.mligo`/`storage.jsligo` like [here](https://github.com/ligolang/dao-jsligo/blob/main/src/storage.jsligo).
And this storage is `#import` 'ed in the main contract file like [here](https://github.com/ligolang/dao-jsligo/blob/main/src/main.jsligo#L6).

You also might want to look at modular [FA2 implementation library](https://github.com/oxheadalpha/nft-tutorial/tree/master/packages/fa2-contracts) (tzgen). [Here](https://github.com/oxheadalpha/nft-tutorial/tree/master/packages/fa2-contracts) is an example how to use it and extend FA2 contracts.

Answer (score 0):

Taqueria is great for this, it compiles your ligo code into michelson, so you can use your initial storage on deployment